# Expected Character for no reason in a JsonPath

Tags: java, rest, jsonpath

Assuming that I have this JSON:

```
{
   "response" : {
      "code" : "XXX",
      "label" : "Lorem Ipsum",
      "items" : [
         {
            "code" : "200",
            "label" : "200 !!!"
         },
         {
            "code" : "300",
            "label" : "300 !!!!!"
         },
         {
            "code" : "500",
            "label" : "+500 !!!!!"
         }]
   }
}
```

I want to get the label of the item when `code` = 500 (as for example) in Java.

I'm using `jayWay` Library and this jsonPath:

```
"$.response.items[?(@.code='500')].label"
```

I'm getting this error while parsing : `Expected character: )`

The java code :

```
public static String getElementValueByJsonPath(String jsonContent, String jsonPath) {

        if (checkJsonValidity(jsonContent)) {
            String returnedValue ="";
            Configuration config = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS);
            try {
                returnedValue = ""+JsonPath.using(config).parse(jsonContent).read(jsonPath);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            return returnedValue;

        } 
        return null;
```

Anyone knows why I have this error, and can I bypass it with another library or method.

Thanks

Comment: Is the example json you posted the actual json used by the program? If not, please post the actual json used.

Comment: @FlexEast Yes it's the actual json, i changed codes and labels

Comment: If you go to https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ ( which uses jayway ) and enter the same data and path you will see this is not a valid jsonpath query for jayway, or two of the other implementations, the only one that does not fail outright does not return what you are expecting. I think you need to go back and re-read the jsonpath/jayway documentation as this syntax is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error for a very valid reason, that is not a valid jsonpath query.

If you go to https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ ( which uses jayway ) and enter the same data and path you will see this is not a valid jsonpath query for jayway, or two of the other implementations, the only one that does not fail outright does not return what you are expecting. I think you need to go back and re-read the [jsonpath documentation](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) as this syntax clearly is not valid.

The correct syntax is `$.response.items[?(@.code=='500')].label` as the [documentation clearly states](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

I would not rely on implementations that do not fail on incorrect syntax.

Comment: does that curiousconcept..com website use jayway ( answer is no ) which makes its result irrelevant. it fails on the non-"flow communications" implementations that are actually compliant which tells me that website is less-than-useless if it accepts non-compliant queries.